# Why doesn't fputcsv write to my csv file?

Tags: php, ajax, csv

I've been trying to write to a .csv file using PHP although for some reason the file stays blank and no data is added. Firstly I send an AJAX post request to addComment.php which should then append the POST data to a csv file.
Here is the JS code

```
submit.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  var data = {
    body:commentBody.value,
    rating:rating.value.trim(),
    id:id,
    category:category.trim()
  };

  $.post("addComment.php", data, handleRes);
  //handleRes just logs the response data

  });
```

The PHP file should now take the $_POST data and append to a csv file(Which is currently blank)
Here is the PHP script

```
ob_start();
session_start();
$body = $_POST["body"];
$rating = $_POST["rating"];
$category = trim($_POST["category"]);
$name = $_SESSION["username"];
$id = $_POST["id"];

$filepath = "./data/comments/" . $category . ".csv");
$csvLine = array($name, $body, $rating);
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filepath'");
$output = fopen("php://output", "w");
fputcsv($output, $csvLine, "|");
fclose($output);
```

Comment: Have you closed your file pointer? `fclose($output);`

Comment: Just done that, cheers, still a blank file though and it's logging the data i the format I want it to be input into the file too! `Matthew|Helllo|1`

Comment: you've too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: You know a solution?

Comment: I *think* you may just be writing to the output buffer and not the csv file itself. If you want it in the CSV file, you'll have to open that file, append to it, then close it.

Comment: This approach works best is there a way I can upvote this comment?

Comment: @aynber -------

Comment: Glad I could help. I don't think you have the rep to upvote comments yet.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Probably because you have output buffering turned on, so the output is not being directed to the specified output buffer (STDOUT, in this case) but collected in the output buffer.

I think you can call `ob_end_flush()` at the end to flush the contents to the intended output.